# $x^3 - x^2 - 2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Well if we define the obvious homomorphisms  from $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and from $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we see the following -

In $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 = (x)(x^2 + x)$

In $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$

Now if $f(x)$ was reducible these factors would be of the same degree in both $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible.

I am not sure if this is correct as I know this process works when dealing with polynomials defined in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but here we are starting with a polynomial defined in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

So is there correct? And if not, how do I determine if this polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: For a more direct proof: A cubic polynomial is irreducible if and only if it has no roots (why?). So it suffices to check that $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, which is fairly immediate, since $$f(0) = 3, f(1) = 3, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 1, f(4) = 1$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+-+x%5E2+-+2

Comment: What may appear to be homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z/5$ to $\mathbb Z/2$ are _not_ homomorphisms at all. They are not even well defined: for example, $1\mod 5=6\mod 5$, which supposedly would go to both $1\mod 2$ and $0\mod 2$. Impossible.

Comment: "obvious homomorphisms"? Which ones??

Comment: Does it make sense to have a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z_5}\to \mathbb{Z_2}$? Unless you are talking about the zero map, if the obvious homorphism is what I think you mean, then you are sending zeroes to nonzero elements, which cannot happen.

Comment: @paulgarrett Cheers I see that now.

Comment: Corrected wrong (unfortunately common) notation.